# HTML output takes too long to load and to show up the scroll bar

Tags: html, output, r-markdown, scrollbar

I have this Rmarkdown file but since it is pretty heavy (it is an online guide), the scroll bar (and the whole file except the first page) takes too long to show up when opening the html output. I tried to divide the rmd file into distinct rms sub files as below shown but I still  can't get the result. Thank you

````
---
title: "my_file"
author: "me"
date: "26/02/2020"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float:
      collapsed: yes
      smooth_scroll: yes
  word_document: default
---

```{r child = 'child0.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'child1.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'child2.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'child3.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'child4.Rmd'}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Investigate and try to reduce the size of yours pictures/graphics : in parallel or alternatively to the 'split' of your text in several 'html-pages', the idea is to made a compromise between time of opening and quality of your graphics (and imported pictures).

So, try :

- to reduce size of graphics computed by some code chunk, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154819/9959115) for an exemple.
- to reduce the size of yours imported pictures, if they huge, by resizing them.
- to take advantage of the html format which is able to render svg files : try encoding in svg your graphics representation of your data. Not your external images, only your computation which resulting in graphics (text + area + color = some graphics are 'lighter' in svg than in jps or tif).